# Sentences within a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, sentence, writing-style, sentence-meaning, formatting

Is there a standard way to manage sentences within a sentence?  For example:

> Using the following definition
>
> Definition 1: A graph G is isomorphic to another graph H if there is an isomorphism f from the vertices of G to the vertices of H.  Further, f(v)f(u) is an edge of H if and only if vu is an edge of G.
>
> in the following lemma,
>
> Lemma 2: Let H and G be isomorphic graphs.  If there is a set of t vertices that disconnect H then there is a set of t vertices that disconnect G.
>
> we obtain the following theorem
>
> Theorem 3: Suppose H is isomorphic to G. 
> Then the connectivity of H is equal to the connectivity of G.

Is this grammatically correct, or should it be presented in a different way?

Comment: Although your question is clear and interesting, it may not be a good fit at this site because many participants here think that questions about formatting, punctuation, or spelling aren't really questions about English language and usage. (The implicit premise of this view is that formatting, punctuation, and spelling are features of written language, whereas grammar is a feature of spoken language.) From their perspective, you've asked a question that you say is about grammaticality—but they don't see any grammatical issue to answer. Hence the "needs details or clarity" criticism. ...

Comment: ... I can't offer a formal answer to your question because it has been closed, but in my view, you have already handled the sentences-within-a-sentence difficulty quite well. My only additional advice would be to indent the text blocks for Definition 1, Lemma 2, and Theorem 3 as display text blocks while leaving the linking segments of the sentence ("Using the following definition" and "in the following lemma," and "we obtain the following theorem") on separate lines that start flush left (not indented). You could add a colon after "theorem"—but otherwise I think the punctuation is fine as is.

Comment: I just voted to leave the question closed, because I believe that the stated close reason applies and has not been addressed  — *I **don’t understand what the question is.***  What sentence(s) are within other sentence(s)?  What do you mean by “manage”?  Are you asking about grammaticality, sentence meaning, or what?

Comment: @SvenYargs: Why do you believe that the question is about formatting, punctuation or spelling?  The OP’s words are “How should I manage sentences within a sentence?” and “Is this grammatically correct …?”  The OP selected the tags “grammaticality” and “sentence-meaning”.  I don’t see anything about formatting, except for your contributions.

Comment: @Scott: The poster wants to know how he should handle a sentence that has full-sentence blocks of text embedded in it. His sentence is as follows: "Using the following definition [Definition 1 text block] in the following lemma [Lemma 2 text block] we obtain the following theorem [Theorem 3 text block]." He wants to know how to punctuate/format that text so that it is clear that he is presenting a continuous statement about the three blocks of text. It's a pretty straightforward question, in my opinion. And if I'm mistaken, I trust that the OP will set me straight.

Comment: @SvenYargs Yes that's what I'm asking, basically if the definitions lemmas... are short e.g.  Using the definition a=b and the lemma b<c, we get the theorem a<c.  This seems fine.  But what if the definition lemma and theorem themselves are several sentences long?    is  "Using the following definition [Definition 1 text block] in the following lemma [Lemma 2 text block] we obtain the following theorem [Theorem 3 text block]."  a good idea or not?  Or should I just state and label the theorems and refer to them by number in the sentence?

Comment: @HaoS: To avoid yet another tripwire in the EL&U close-voting minefield, you would do well not to ask whether something is "a good idea or not"—because close voters will seize on that question to assert that you are soliciting opinion-based answers, and "opinion-based" queries are explicitly off-topic at this site. However, there is what I take to be an on-topic question at the heart of your posted question, which is something like this: "Do style guides generally agree on a standard way to handle sentences that contain multiple embedded sentences like this one? If so, what do they recommend?"